# Port change from 80 to 443 causing endless user prompting when accessing office files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, excel, https

This weekend I changed the main web application to run on https instead of http.

This morning when some (not all) users try to check out or edit and office file they are continually prompted for their credentials even if they enter the correct username and password.

The only other thing I changed was added "https" to the trusted file location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Those users may not have the https variant of the sharepoint URLs in their 'Trusted Sites' list.  See the below site for more info:

http://www.uta.edu/oit/cs/software/microsoft/sharepoint/how_to/sp_auto_login/index.php

Also, it is a properly signed SSL certificate?

Comment: Yes it's a properly signed certificate. I'll troubleshoot the trusted sites list and report back. Thanks for the help.